# Overlap columns between two dataframes

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df) that I need to annotate:

[image: locations I need to annotate]

The location columns contains a coordinate that has to lie within a gene to be annotated. This means the chromosome columns have to match, and coordinate > gene start position & coordinate < gene end position.

I have a list of possible genes (gen) as well:
[image: genes I want to use]

I want to add another column to df: df$Gene, that contains the name of the gene. Multiple genes can be annotated to one location. I have this working in a very slow way, but am lost on how to make it faster. Anybody any hints on how to approve annotation speed?

```
genes <- list()
for(del_id in 1:nrow(df)) {
   gen_id <- which(gen$Chromosome == df[del_id,]$Chromosome & gen$Start <= df[del_id,]$location & gen$End >= df[del_id,]$location)
   genes[[del_id]] <- gen[gen_id, ]$Gene
}


df$Gene <- sapply(genes, function( x ) { ifelse( any( is.na(x) ), NA, paste( x, collapse = ',' ) ) } )
```

Comment: You should use the `GenomicRanges` package from bioconductor. It was built specifically to solve this type of problem

Comment: Does it work, can improve my answer?